keep sudo effective without password after update sudo package itself
I want to write an automation script in Bash that requires frequent use of the sudo command. To avoid entering my password repeatedly after the sudo timeout, I've tried the following:
#!/bin/bash
sudo -v
while true; do sleep 1; sudo -v; done &
# simulate a very long task
sudo sleep 601
# still effective in bash script
sudo echo stackoverflow

This allows me to use sudo without re-entering the password. However, after updating sudo, it no longer works:
#!/bin/bash
sudo -v
while true; do sleep 1; sudo -v; done &
# simulate a very long task
sudo sleep 601
# still effective in bash script
sudo echo stackoverflow
sudo dnf update sudo -y
# prompt me to type password again
sudo echo stackoverflow again

After updating sudo, I'm prompted for the password again. How can I maintain sudo access without needing to re-enter the password? Is there a better solution than extending the sudo timestamp_timeout, which I prefer not to do? I can't think of other ways to achieve this. Is extending the timeout the only option?

I use dnf update to update the whole system, which surprisingly break my sudo -v. It took me two days to figure out it involves updating sudo, and that breaks sudo -v

EDIT: There are also many lines without sudo. For example,
systemctl enable --user firstboot-gnome-extension.service
cp -a $HOME/.config ~/dotfiles/

If I run as root user, I have to carefully prepend every non-root line with su - "$SUDO_USER" -c, which does not work for some commands such as systemctl enable --user

Why is this script not running as root?

@Panki Most of the time, I login as a non-root user, and assume I am operating as a non-root user

Perhaps you can update your /etc/sudoers file with something like this %user   ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: /home/user/bin/script.sh it will not request any passwd for the script in your bin directory

Putting many sudo commands into a script is a bit of an anti-pattern.  You would want to remove the sudo from within the script, and instead run the script as root by using sudo ./script.sh and the entire script will run with elevated privileges.

@GracefulRestart When I run the script as root using sudo ./script.sh, I need to modify certain lines, such as changing systemctl enable --user firstboot-gnome-extension.service to su "$SUDO_USER" -c 'systemctl enable --user firstboot-gnome-extension.service'. However, this unexpectedly results in the error 'failed to connect to bus: No medium found', which didn't occur before these changes. Other unexpected issues might also arise from modifying other lines.
